# ListView being restored when returning to MainActivity - Android Java Activities

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-listview

I'm building an app where I allow the user to make edits to the listview, fill it with content in a second activity, and send the results back to the first activity using intents, and display the results as such. This works fine when specifically editing ONE item. If I try to edit another item, the rest of them get restored to the initial value.
[secondactivity throw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vniom.png)

[mainactivity catch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPRDs.png)

Comment: Thats happening because you're recreating the mainactivity so the arrays are recreated with the old values

Comment: Any way to not have that happen?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `SharedPreferences` to store edited values and pass the value of the preference.

Answer (score 0):

`MainActivity` should launch `SecondActivity` using `startActivityForResult()`. `SecondActivity` will do whatever and when it is time to return to `MainActivity`, `SecondActivity` should return an `Intent` with some "extras" that `MainActivity` can use to determine what `View` or `Layout` to show/hide. To return the result, `SecondActivity` should call `setResult()`, not `startActivity()`.

In `MainActivity`, implement `onActivityResult()`. This method will be called when `SecondActivity` finishes, and it will be called with the `Intent` that `SecondActivity` passed to `setResult()`. In `onActivityResult()` you can check the returned `Intent` for the "extras" and you can update the data in `MainActivity` accordingly.

In this way, the data in `MainActivity` can be sent to `SecondActivity` again to edit another item, etc.